# Dll created in TFS not work

Tags: c#, dll, tfs

I tried to created a .dll in TFS using VS2010 and use the .dll in a new project.
However, it keep on returning an error message saying the entity point for the method cannot be found.

To see if there is some error in the code of the class library, I created another class library project but not in TFS this time. This totally works well. This one can be referenced by C# using "using".

However, the one created in TFS cannot be referenced.

I would like to ask, what's the difference between these two .dll I created and what can I do so that I can successfully reference the .dll I created in TFS.

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the DLL built using the TFS build server didn't work?

Comment: @Matthew Yes, it give me the error "Entity Point Not Found". So, I tried to build another one using the same codes but not using TFS, and this one works fine.

Comment: This could be that it is building in x64/x86 mode while the rest of your application is expecting the opposite.

Comment: Are you sure the error isn't "Entry point not found?"

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the error didn't say "Entry Point Not Found"? I have seen this many times when a project is set to build in x86 format when it should be building in x64 or AnyCPU. Right-click on the solution and go to Properties. Click Configuration Properties. Find your project and look at the Platform column. AnyCPU is usually your safest bet.